# c++ catch exceptions when we use inhereted classes

Tags: c++, exception

I have code like this:

```
Class A{};

Class B : A {};

void foo()
{
  throw new B;
}
```

Here we can catch exception only using catch(B *e). But why we can not catch it using catch(A *e).
Is this because private access type in the inheritance?

Comment: Throw exceptions by value and catch by const reference, no need for heap allocations here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's exactly why.

Since `B` inherits `A` privately, no one except `B` is aware of the inheritance.
So a `B` object is not considered an `A` object and cannot be converted to an instance of `A`.